# Google Sheet: How do I text join each column of a range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| Day1 | Day2 | ... | What I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9am | 2pm | ... | Day1-9pm,Day2-2pm |
| 3am |  | ... | Day1-3am |
| 10am | 1pm | ... | Day1-10am, Day2-1pm |

There are unkown days in the above range, what I want to achieve is what the last column shows.
Please note that I get the above range through a `filter`, so I can't use A1notation in this case.

Can this be achieved by formula?

Answer (score 1):

go for:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,     A1&"-"&TEXT(A2:A, "ham/pm")&
              IF(B2:B="",,", "&B1&"-"&TEXT(B2:B, "ham/pm"))))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:1000="",,
 B1:1&"-"&TEXT(B2:1000, "ham/pm,"))),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: The number of columns are uknown, not just COLUMN A and COLUMN B

Comment: @shenkwen answer updated